# Is it possible to use the MariaDB CONNECT Storage engine in MySQL 8?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pivot-table

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-pivot-table-type

Are MariaDB Storage Engines compatible with MySQL? I know the two databases are similar, but not sure if it's possible to exchange the two. Google fails to show any examples of someone doing this.

The main motivation is we need to pivot values from one table as columns (is this value present for this row).

Comment: Storage engines are part of the database implementation, they're not components that can be extracted from one database and used in another.

Comment: 90+% of MySQL and MariaDB are identical, or at least very similar.  However, the "Connect" storage engine is unique to MariaDB.  There is, however, some similarity with 8.0's [_Federated engine_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html)  But, I don't think there is anything like "pivot".  Still, see the tag I added.